# How should the DBPedia live changesets be interpreted with regard to time and edits?

Tags: dbpedia

The changesets at `http://live.dbpedia.org/liveupdates/` seem to be time-ordered, but their interpretation for replay isn't completely clear from surrounding descriptions.

Regarding the paired add and remove files, when an existing value (such as a `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract>`) is edited, does that result in just an 'added' entry with the new value, or a 'removed' of the old, then an 'added' with the new?

After downloading a daily summary tar -- such as `http://live.dbpedia.org/liveupdates/2013/07/2013-07-07.tar.gz` -- the initial untarring gives a large number of top-level added/removed file pairs (1232 to be precise). But then, also, 24 hourly additional tarfiles (`2013-07-07-[00-23].tar.gz`), each with their own added/removed file pairs. Are the top-level files sequenced 'before', 'after' or redundant-with the hourly files?

Answer (score 2):

**DBpedia Live** generates two sets of files added and removed, which contain the added and removed triples respectively.
Upon an article change, the new and old triples are written in nt format and saved to the added/ removed files respectively, and then those files are compressed and stored on the server.
The [DBpedia sync-tool](https://github.com/dbpedia/dbpedia-live-mirror) continuously downloads those files, decompresses them and uses them to update a local mirror of the official [DBpedia Live endpoint](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql).

So, first the old triples are removed from the local mirror, and then the new triples are inserted.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how the top-level added/removed files that are inside the once-daily TAR.GZ files should be interpreted - before or after the individual hourly batches also inside the same TAR.GZ?